# GREP search modification: filter by string

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep

I have following grep command which looks for 'Exception in' string in the logs for past 24 hours via remote machine and prints out next 40 lines.

```
ssh $host $'sed -e "1,/^$(date -d -20hour +\'%Y-%m-%d %H\')/d" /mylogs.out | grep -A40 "Exception in"' >> $log
```

This works well to catch Exceptions such as below:

```
2016-02-08 13:19:34,034 ERROR [qtp859655531-3974] com.project.actions.CustomStatsAction - Exception in .....
```

However, sometimes, the line starts with WARN instead of ERROR and I dont want lines with WARN in my result. Example:

```
2016-02-08 13:19:34,034 WARN [qtp859655531-3974] com.project.actions.CustomStatsAction - Exception in ....
```

How should I modify my query to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grep -A40 -E "ERROR .*Exception in"`

Please notice that `-A` is not standard and is available in GNU's grep.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Append `fgrep -v WARN` to your pipeline to filter out the undesirable lines.

Comment: I think this will just exclude the WARN string however; I do not want to process the data at all if it starts with WARN.

Comment: It should exclude all lines containing WARN from the output.  If you want to skip processing the WARN lines, change the start of your sed expression to:

Comment: @GregTarsa : My query is based on 'Exception in' string. So, I need to print  next 40 lines if there is 'Exception in' string AND line is not starting with WARN

Comment: Yes, I see that now.  Adding a command do the `sed`  expression to delete the WARN is more what you are looking for.  BTW, if the `grep -A` option is not available, you can tack `| head -40` to the end of the command to get the same effect.  (I like to use the most vanilla options possible.)

Answer (score 0):

The `fgrep -v` answer, above, should exclude all lines containing WARN from the output.  If you really want to skip processing the WARN lines, change  your sed expression to remove all lines containing WARN.

Adding the following extra command to the start of your `sed` expression should do the trick.  You are adding a command to delete all lines containing WARN before you do your other sed magic. Put it right inside your first double quote.

```
ssh $host $'sed -e "/WARN/d;1,/^$(date -d -20hour +\'%Y-%m-%d %H\')/d" /mylogs.out | grep -A40 "Exception in"'
```

Comment: :something like this? `ssh $host $'sed -e "/WARN/d 1,/^$(date -d -20hour +\'%Y-%m-%d %H\')/d" /mylogs.out | grep -A40 "Exception in"'`   This actually gives some syntax error. Sorry to bother but I am new to shell scripting

Comment: put a semi-colon right after the `d`.  `sed` allows you to combine commands on a line (or in an expression) that way.  I'll amend my answer to make this clearer.